# Momentjs locale-specific weekdays()

Tags: javascript, momentjs

In moment there is a function `moment.weekdays()` that returns an array from sunday - saturday

If I change my locale to EU where first day of the week is monday, for example finland(`moment.locale('fi')`)

the result of `moment.weekdays()` is still starting with (translated) sunday

also: this doesn't change moment.weekdays() result but changes moment.weekday(1) to monday

```
moment.updateLocale('fi', {
    week: {
        dow : 1 // Monday is the first day of the week
    }
});
```

Is there a way to get weekdays for current locale in the right order(starting with monday) or is modifying the `moment.weekdays()` array myself the only way?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> As of 2.13.0 you can pass a bool as the first parameter of the weekday functions. If true, the weekdays will be returned in locale specific order. For instance, in the Arabic locale, Saturday is the first day of the week

For your example in French, this would look like:

```
moment.locale("fr")
moment.weekdays(true)
```

output:

```
["lundi", "mardi", "mercredi", "jeudi", "vendredi", "samedi", "dimanche"]
```

[link to documentation](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/listing-months-weekdays/)

Comment: Matthew's answer wasn't working for me. For french names, I had to go with:    ```let frenchDays = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6].map(day => moment().locale('fr').weekday(day).format('dddd'));```

Comment: It should be noted that, as the docs say: 
By default, Moment.js comes with English (United States) locale strings. If you need other locales, you can load them into Moment.js for later use.
You can read more about it here: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/changing-locale/